# No signal on monitor after secure boot

Tags: boot, hdmi, uefi, secure-boot, windows-11

I want to install windows 11

So i open the bios and enable tpm (intel ppm) and then disable csm and enable secure boot after use default key

After restart i got blank screen no signal
And no bios

I use hdmi connection between gpu to monitor i didn't have integrated graphics card

I use google to find fix for this problem but i didn't found it yet

Ot try to clear cmos
And unplug ram + gpu + harddisk + use dvi cable

Nothing happen still no signal

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/

Then i found this firmware update for gpu but i use hdmi not dp

So is this firmware update can fix it or just for display port?

My pc

Cpu - i5-9400f

Gpu - Gtx 1060

Motherboard - H310m s2h 2.0

Ram - 16gb

1 hdd

Comment: Just a small comment. How did you reset (clear) BIOS? By removing the CMOS battery or shorting the pins on mobo? I find shorting pins more reliable than removing  battery.

Comment: I have tried these two methods - after i power my pc its restart so i think i successfully reset my bios but didn't fix my problem still no signal in my monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There just one answer for this problem

I fix it with buy cheaper cpu what compatibility with my motherboard
Celeron g4900 it have integrated gpu

Install it and unplug nividia gpu then connected dvi to motherboard (hdmi not work for me idk why)
Then simply disable secure boot ,enable csm and restore default settings

Then you can plug nividia gpu

Note:
Uefi firmware update above can't fix this problem hdmi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the i3 9100f processor. I took my motherboard to the service center and they put a processor with integrated graphics in it and plugged the display directly into the motherboard HDMI port. Then everything showed up and they reset my bios and gave the motherboard back to me. Hope this helps. If you can find a CPU with integrated graphics, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you , i live in small city - idk if computer service center there have 8th or 9th generation processor i will try