# turning on secure boot gives only a black screen

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, nvidia-graphics-card, secure-boot

I have installed Windows 10 with secure boot off and now I want to install Windows 11. So I turned secure boot back on but, only a black screen shows after computer boots.

What I see - I can see POST LEDs passing on the Mobo and fans spinning, it looks like the computer boots but does not give the output.

PC specs - CPU AMD Ryzen 5 3600, MSI MPG B550 Gaming plus Mobo, 16GB RAM, Nvidia GT 710 VGA (this is just for video out),

I searched the internet and found similar questions [here](https://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/6047/710-secure-boot-uefi-driver) and [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/blank-screen-after-enabling-secure-boot.3710149/) but, could not find an answer yet. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Is your drive set for GPT and are you using UEFI?

Comment: @John Yes it is GPT and UEFI

Comment: Perhaps try a Windows 10 Startup Repair with the installation media on a bootable USB key

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Firmware settings (As tried by other user in second link)? Clear the CMOS by shorting 2 relevant Pins on the motherboard. Hopefully that should clear Secure Boot. If reset works, you should be able to get back to Firmware Settings (BIOS/UEFI). Then try updating BIOS if newer version is available and retry.

Answer (score 0):

[No signal on monitor after secure boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1680355/no-signal-on-monitor-after-secure-boot)

I ask the same question  here and i answer it after i fix the problem
So i will copy my answer

‐-------------------------------------------------

There just one answer for this problem   I fix it with buy cheaper cpu what compatibility with my motherboard  Celeron g4900 it have integrated gpu  Install it and unplug nividia gpu then connected dvi to motherboard (hdmi not work for me idk why) Then simply disable secure boot ,enable csm and restore default settings   Then you can plug nividia gpu

‐----------------------------

Myabe you can fix it with bios flash button  - my mb didn't have button so i didn't try

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue here. To revert the change you need to unplug your GPU then plug your monitor directly into the motherboard. Now when you turn on the computer you can access your bios and turn secure boot off.

Comment: Processor MUST have integrated graphics.

Answer (score -1):

First thing, you have to connect to Integrated graphics card in your PC and you have to have Windows on USB stick.
When your PC will turn on, the secure boot will be enabling so your BIOS become UEFI not legacy you have to startup setup Windows installation click <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> the cmd will switch.

Comment: you mean a processor with integrated graphics?